# how to do bytea in GORM?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have the following model:

```
type User struct {
    UserId    string                `sql:"primary_key;"type:bytea"`
    Username  string
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
}
```

I  want the UserId to be type of bytea . The above doesn't work when trying to create a table:

```
db.CreateTable(&User{})
```

Comment: I found the solution     UserId    []byte

Answer (score 4):

```
type User struct {
    UserId    string                `gorm:"primary_key;type:bytea"`
    Username  string
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers may solve the problem but they are much more useful if you explain how they solve it. Community requires theory as well as code both to understand your answer fully.

Comment: but i found the solution, it should be     UserId    []byte

Comment: @IzabelaIzabela can you provide an example using []byte instead?, thnx